# What causes things to gain the speed of nearby gravitational sources?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, velocity, speed

While I’m aware that this probably has a really simple answer, I can’t figure it out. For example, humans, apples, but also things outside of earth like the ISS travel along with the earth, at the speed of earth just as the earth travels along with the sun at its speed, etc.

It has to be gravity, but how does that explain that we have the same velocity as earth? Say the earth is moving at 20 km/s and an asteroid flies into the earths ‘gravitational field’ at 10 km/s. When would it gain the velocity of 20 km/s, how would it?

Comment: For one thing, the ISS and satellites were all made from materials that were part of the Earth and had its velocity to begin with, and their speeds were added to in order to get them into orbit

Comment: You’re correct, I didn’t think about it that way , my question still stands though. What causes these materials to have this speed in the first place? How do additional materials that have crashed into earth (e.g. remnants of meteorites) gain this speed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not gravity - just conservation of momentum. It takes a lot of hard work to make something launched from Earth lose the momentum that it has inherited from being sat on Earth and go into an orbit much closer to the Sun, for example. This is why the [Parker Solar Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) had to make seven flybys of Venus to change its momentum enough to get close to the Sun - even though it was launched on top of [one of the most powerful rockets ever built](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_IV_Heavy).

Similarly, meteors that arrive in the Earth's atmosphere from further out in the Solar System have to lose a lot of momentum. They generally achieve this by destructive [aerobraking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobraking).

Comment: Alright this makes sense to me, but what I really meant with my question was: How did it gain that momentum from ‘sitting’ on earth in the first place?

Comment: @vac If it didn't have that momentum it wouldn't be sitting on the Earth, it'd be some other place. ;)

Comment: I’m sorry this is pretty hard to grasp for me. Does that mean that things slower than earth could never make it onto earth, and things faster than earth could be smashed into earth ‘adding’ to its mass (unless they are faster than the escape velocity of course)? What would this do to the momentum of the thing smashing into earth and earth itself?

Comment: To add to my comment above, if something slower than earth was on a course for earth (for simplicity, lets say we have a 2d plane where earth is moving from left to right at 2 km/s, and an meteorite is moving from right to left at 1 km/s) it would have less momentum than earth, but it could still enter, how? Wouldn’t it just fall off by that logic? @PM2Ring

Comment: @vac Momentum is always conserved. But the Earth has much more mass than a meteoroid, so when they collide it affects the velocity of the meteoroid a lot more than the Earth's. Some collisions are elastic: bodies bounce off each other, exchanging momentum & kinetic energy. But most collisions are (to some extent) inelastic: momentum is still conserved, but kinetic energy is converted to heat, and creates deformation of the bodies.

Comment: @vac The formation of the Solar System was a messy, time-consuming process. A vast cloud of gas & dust fell together, due to gravity. A lot of the stuff fell into the centre and became the Sun. But many small lumps were formed too, stuck together by chemical forces (electromagnetism) and gravity, which (after many collisions) became the planets, moons, comets, asteroids & meteoroids. A lot of stuff got ejected, too. If you want to know more details about this process, we have some good questions about it on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> Say the earth is moving at 20 km/s and an asteroid flies into the earths ‘gravitational field’ at 10 km/s. When would it gain the velocity of 20 km/s, how would it?

Let's say an asteroid is floating in space and earth comes from the left, moving to the right.

Now when the earth's atmosphere and asteroid are overlapping, the asteroid experiences a wind that is blowing to the right, this causes the asteroid to accelerate to the right, until it moves with the air at the same speed. Now earth and asteroid move at the same speed.

---

Let's say an asteroid is floating in space and a donut shaped planet with no atmosphere comes from the left, moving to the right.

Now when the asteroid goes through the hole, it does not experience any forces, this causes the asteroid to stay still and not start to move with the planet.

Comment: Oh, aerobraking was explained already. Sorry I didn't read carefully.